# Error while passing variables for keyword match using sed

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, sed

I am writing a bash script for text processing where this command is giving me error:

```
sed -e "/\<$7\>/ /\<$5\>/$6/" < "$2/$1" > "file.tmp"
```

This is producing following error:

```
> Unrecognized command: /\<key\>/ /\<Hi\>/Hello/
```

What am I doing wrong?

The values of variables are same as in error.

"$2/$1" are filepath and filename

Comment: I am not able to display error properly in question.
Unrecognized command: /\<key\>/ /\<Hi\>/Hello/

Comment: You should explain more, what is the expected output ? what values would `$1..$7` hold etc.

Comment: When you use variables in sed, you need to quote them like `'$7'`

Comment: @rahul I tried what you said still giving same error.

Comment: @Menon Let me see if i get your problem. If the line in the file matches $7, you'd like to replace $5 with $6? your missing an 's' there `sed -e "/\<'$7'\>/s/\<'$5'\>/'$6'/" < "$2/$1" > "file.tmp"`

Comment: @rahul......yes, the missing 's' caused the error.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: @rahul you may as well post that as an answer so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if i get your problem. If the line in the file matches $7, you'd like to replace $5 with $6? your missing an 's' there

`sed -e "/\<'$7'\>/s/\<'$5'\>/'$6'/" < "$2/$1" > "file.tmp"`